# Load Content Script when ui is launched by Browser Action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome Extension such that it uses browser_action to place a button on the task bar, and on the click of that button it opens a web page. That web page html is packaged inside the extension (not a hosted site). So when I click, it opens

```
chrome-extension://<app-id>/ui/index.html
```

I want to have a content script run when this page opens. I tried

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["chrome-extension://<app-id>/ui/index.html"],
            "css": ["css/main.css"],
            "js": ["js/content2.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
```

But Chrome doesn't load the extension. How can this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading jQuery into chrome-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035242/loading-jquery-into-chrome-extension)

Comment: See also my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26610043/934239